# QGIS 3 Raster calculator output file

Tags: raster-calculator, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3 raster calculator.

I write the operation I want and, when I click on the three dots to select the output layer (as usual), the program doesn't allow me to give a name and create a new output file. It asks me to enter a result file instead.

Why is that, and how is it done?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18303), which has been addressed and implemented. If you get the nightly build, this shouldn't be problem.

If you just want to leave your software alone until the next "official" update, you can address this problem by typing the full filepath and filename into the text box. Effective, if somewhat irritating.

Comment: I think you should include some description telling others that the solution you suggest requires that you rebuild QGIS from scratch (with the change to the `cpp` file). Thus your solution isn't within reach of most users, but they don't know that if they don't know  what a `cpp` file is.

Comment: Good point. Answer has been edited.